# how to use tortoise svn with zend studio

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, zend-studio, collabnet

I have installed Tortoise SVN in my windows7 OS. I use Zend Studio 5.5 for PHP development and trying to use tortoiseSVN with Zend Studio, but no luck so far.
Does anyone know how to set up tortoise svn with zend studio?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck" ? Zend Studio has an SVN integration itself (as far as i know) furthermore TortoiseSVN is a separate Tool for SVN not an IDE integration....

Comment: Ohh! I know that. But zend's integrated SVN has stopped working, then? what will you do?

Comment: Why has it stopped working ? Have you upgraded to SVN 1.7? It might be simpler to stuck with SVN 1.6 till Zend will update to 1.7..(I've checked you are using a really old version of Zend Studio!!).

Comment: Don't know why it has stopped working. I haven't updated anything in SVN. that's why I decided to go with tortoise SVN.

Comment: You are looking for an SVN Connector, SVNKit should do the trick. Here's how to enable it: http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/content/working%20with%20svn%201.7%20connector.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseSVN and Zend Studio are completely different and independent tools. They are not meant to work together, only separately.

Answer (score 1):

1. The ToroiseSVN client is independent from Zend Studio and does not integrate to it.
2. Your stock svn-connector in your Studio installation is outdated.

But: Older Zend Studio and newer SVN-Versions will work together, as soon as you switch your installed svn plugin to the native library of Tigris.

This is a (german) blog post which describes the install procedure for ZendStudio 8 and SVN Repository version 1.7: 
http://softwareentwickler.blogspot.com/2011/11/svn-17-mit-zend-studio-9.html

This also worked like a charm with Zend Studio 7.2.1 and svn 1.7